# Cannot use class in jsp

Tags: jsp

I'm trying to use a class I defined in a package in my Java Web Project, however I keep getting errors when I use the class I defined in the package. The error is saying that the class cannot be resolved to a type. I am importing the package that I made that contains the class that I want to use.

Comment: For future questions, an exact copypaste of the error/exception message and stacktrace would be more then helpful. Also a snippet of how you're importing and using it would be helpful. Otherwise it's a bit of guessing to the real cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class needs to be located in webapp's `/WEB-INF/classes` in a folder structure which represents the declared `package`. So if you have for example

```
package com.example;

public class Foo {
    // ...
}
```

then you should have a `/WEB-INF/classes/com/example/Foo.class` file. Please keep in mind that this is case sensitive as everything else in Java.

Another possible cause is when you're trying to use it in a `<jsp:useBean>` tag, that it should have a (implicit) default constructor which doesn't throw an exception upon construction.