# JSP Cannot Use Class In Java Resources

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I am using eclipse to manage a JSP project, and I cant seem to use my Java class. The exception being raised looks like this:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP: 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP: 

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 10 in the jsp file: /Login.jsp
UserSession cannot be resolved to a type
7: <body>
8:  <%
9:      File user = new File("C:\\Users\\Elijah\\" + request.getParameter("usr") + ".csv");
10:         UserSession usr = new UserSession(request.getParameter("usr"));
11:     
12:         FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(user);
13:         DataInputStream reader = new DataInputStream(fstream);


An error occurred at line: 10 in the jsp file: /Login.jsp
UserSession cannot be resolved to a type
7: <body>
8:  <%
9:      File user = new File("C:\\Users\\Elijah\\" + request.getParameter("usr") + ".csv");
10:         UserSession usr = new UserSession(request.getParameter("usr"));
11:     
12:         FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(user);
13:         DataInputStream reader = new DataInputStream(fstream);


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:468)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 logs.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
```

After some looking around, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588064/cannot-use-class-in-jsp). It is not helpful, however, because eclipse doesn't let me do that. I make the classes folder, but then when I attempt to make the package, it throws it into java resources, not letting me put it in WEB-INF. Is there some other way I can manage this. There is a lib folder in WEB-INF generated in eclipse, but I don't know if it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed to import the `UserSession` class in the JSP. Simply use `import` page directive to import the classes in JSP at the very beginning of the file.

```
<%@ page import="com.x.y.z.UserSession" %>
```

OR use fully-qualified name of the class.

```
com.x.y.z.UserSession usr=new com.x.y.z.UserSession(request.getParameter("usr"));
```

---

### The page directive

The page directive can contain the list of all the imported packages.  To import more than one item, separate the package names by commas, e.g.

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*,java.text.*" %>
```

Comment: What if it is of the default class?

Comment: What do you mean by default class? any package other than `java.lang` must be imported if used.

Answer (score 1):

You have to import UserSession Class in to jsp, using import directive.

Syntax for Import page directive is:

you can even import multiple classes using one directive by separating them with comma

You can go through this article:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/java.817/a83726/genlovw3.htm